# 3 digits for alternative example of Keith Wood's Jquery Countdown

Tags: jquery, date, timer, countdown

For the Jquery countdown plugin created by Keith Wood, we would like to use the "Alternative Images" version, but our countdown datetime is currently in 3 digits for the number of days.  The script is currently only showing 2 digits of the 3 digits for the number of days left, cutting off hundreds digit.

An example can be viewed at http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html under the Layouts tab, last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try adding an image{d100} span?  Based on the documentation, this should work:

```
$('#glowingLayout').countdown({until: liftoffTime, compact: true, 
    layout: '<span class="image{d100}"></span>' + 
        '<span class="image{d10}"></span><span class="image{d1}"></span>' + 
        '<span class="imageDay"></span><span class="imageSpace"></span>' + 
        '<span class="image{h10}"></span><span class="image{h1}"></span>' + 
        '<span class="imageSep"></span>' + 
        '<span class="image{m10}"></span><span class="image{m1}"></span>' + 
        '<span class="imageSep"></span>' + 
        '<span class="image{s10}"></span><span class="image{s1}"></span>'});
```

Comment: Ahh, now that makes sense!  Its a span for EACH digit.  Thank you!